# Unique RegEx string

Tags: .net, regex

I have a set of requirements which state that the input must be validated as follows:

- Be between 1 and 7 characters
- Numeric
- Greater than 0
- and allow a decimal point

Currently I have `^(?!0{1,7}$)(\d+(\.\d)?){1,7}$`

But this does not limit the overall string to a maximum of 7 characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can think this way:

```
^(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)?$)(?![0\.]+$).{1,7}$
```

- Positive lookahead from the beginning: it should be composed of
  digits and optional `.` symbol (number pattern)
- Negative lookahead from the beginning: it shouldn't be composed only of
  `0` and `.` symbols (pattern to exclude 0 value).
- It should have between 1 and 7 symbols.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: +1 I like your way of think. You may use non capturing groups in instead of Group 1 and 2.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for suggestion, I updated the answer, picture now looks more clear.

Answer (score 4):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!0\.0$)(?:[1-9]|(?<=[1-9]|\.)0|0?\.(?=\d+)){1,7}$
```

- We allow any digit between 1 and 9 (inclusive).
- `0` is allowed only in two cases:

  - if preceded by a non null digit or the decimal point.
  - if followed by the decimal and some numbers.
- Up to 7 characters are allowed.

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/kI2gB9

Comment: @M42 I have updated the regex for matching `10` and other values.

Comment: It's OK for `10` but not for `0.0101` or `10.012` :-(

Comment: @M42 I have simplified the regex and it solves the last issues.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is going to do the trick:

```
^(?!0*(\.0*)?$)(?=.{1,7}$)\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

test: http://jsfiddle.net/29jR6/1/

Comment: `"123f567"` is matched.